# phraseology verb "peer out"

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning

> 1)We **peered out from the window at** the tanks passing through the streets.
> 2)No one wants to walk in bare feet across the frigid floor to **peer out the window at** the icy rain slanting down in the early morning gloom

Why does in the first sentence "from" go before "the window" but in  a latter example it is omitted?

Comment: I would always say _out of the window_, but some English speakers omit the _of_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can say "peered out of the window", "peered out from the window" or just "peered from the window" or "peered out the window".

I would say that "out of" is most common but it depends on the individual.

If there is a difference between using "of" and "from" I would say it is very subtle. Possibly, using "from" emphasizes the window's role as the viewing point slightly more as we use "from" in sentences such as "From the window, he saw the tanks".